# Does Windows Phone 7 have ISynchronizeInvoke

Tags: windows-phone-7

Heading says it all I just can't seem to find it anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be looking for

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( () => { /* your ui update code */ } );
```

Comment: Yeah that's what I am using currently but I wanted to handle thread syncing in my class. Il leave this open for a little bit to see if its available if not il give you the Green tick.